# Unknown algo type: word2vec

Tags: python, h2o

We have created a word2vec model over Python H2O API on version 3.13.0.3975.
When we issued a h2o.get_model on the previously created word2vec model Python API
gives an error.

> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\h2o\h2o.py", line 714, in get_model
>   raise ValueError("Unknown algo type: " + algo)
>   ValueError: Unknown algo type: word2vec

As we look at the h2o.py, there is no algo definition about word2vec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for pointing this out. It will be fixed in the next version of H2O (3.14) coming up next week.

In the meantime please use this code as a workaround to retrieve the model:

```
model_json = h2o.api("GET /3/Models/%s" % model_id)["models"][0]
m = H2OWord2vecEstimator()
m._resolve_model(model_id, model_json)
```

Comment: Thanks for this immediate answer. Worked like a charm in our project.